# System type of Visibility in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am newbie to C# programming language.
My problem is writing a method that use "item.Visibility" attribute and checking visibility.
The pseudo code of it:

```
private void MenuItem_Check(MenuItem item){
     if ((item.Visibility.ToString()=="Hidden") ||(item.Visibility.ToString()=="Collapsed") )
     item.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
}
```

My best regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: @Martin Liversage: Sorry for wrong code and thanks for correction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't really care whether or not the item is hidden or collapsed - you're merely interested in verifying that it's not already visible before you *make it* visible. So check for that:

```
private void MenuItem_Check(MenuItem item){
     // if item is not already visible, make it visible
     if (item.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
        item.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
}
```

This has the added advantage of allowing your code to keep working when the `Visibility.OnlyWithXRayGoggles` constant is added to the [Visibility enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx) in .NET 6.0.

(As the other answers have pointed out already, there's no good reason to convert the value to a string - you can compare directly with the enumeration constants themselves)

Comment: Keep going, remove the if() statement.

Comment: @Hans: Not terribly familiar with WPF - is there a penalty for setting this property without actually changing it? (does this trigger events, force layout recalculation, or is it smart enough to notice that nothing's actually changed)

Answer (score 3):

No need for `ToString()` .. `Visibility` is an enumeration...

```
private void MenuItem_Check(MenuItem item){
     if (item.Visibility == Visiblity.Hidden || item.Visibility == Visiblity.Collapsed)
        item.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void MenuItem_Check(MenuItem item)
{
     if ((item.Visibility == Visibility.Hidden) || 
         (item.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed))
     {
         item.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
     }
}
```